# Which races existed before the gods?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, forgotten-realms, lore

The D&D 5e Monster Manual says this in the aboleth section:

> ABOLETH: 
>   **Before the coming of the gods**, aboleths lurked in 
>   primordial oceans and underground lakes. They 
>   reached out with their minds and seized control of the 
>   **burgeoning life-forms of the mortal realm**, making those 
>   creatures their slaves. Their dominance made them 
>   like gods. Then the true gods appeared, smashing the 
>   aboleths' empire and freeing their slaves. 
>   Aboleths have never forgotten.

This seems to state that besides the aboleths, other mortal beings existed before the gods.

Which races were these?

I'm specifically looking for answers from the Forgotten Realms setting.

Comment: Vaguely related: [What was behind the creation of the gods/planes?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30493)

Comment: worth noting "coming of the gods" is different than "existence of the gods'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This bit of creature lore isn't precisely compatible with [the Forgotten Realms' creation story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sel%C3%BBne#Description_in_the_Forgotten_Realms_setting).

There were no primordial oceans or underground lakes before the coming of the Forgotten Realms gods for aboleths to rule from. In the Realms, at least three gods existed before oceans and lakes even could: **Selûne** and **Shar** sprang from the featureless void, and they created **Chauntea** to be the planet itself.

Life was created by these three gods, so there was no time before the gods that any life could have existed for aboleths to have ruled imperially over.

At least not in the Forgotten Realms. Perhaps the Faerûnian aboleths are migrants from a reality where they did have such a pre-divine empire and they brought their grudges with them when moving to the post-divine Realms.

In any case: **there were no races before the gods, at least not in the Forgotten Realms.**

Comment: I agree, and I think it supports my comment about the fluff being rather "unreliable" and flexible because it inherits that relativism from the old pulp novels like Lovecraft's and Howard's stuff.

Comment: I realize this question is old, and it appears that the linked document has changed—at any rate, I could not find any supporting text for this answer in the page linked, which now appears to be about the (out of universe) development of the Forgotten Realms setting, not the (in universe) creation story of the Forgotten Realms. This question could be significantly improved by a new/permanent reference that backs up the claim that the Forgotten Realms creation story is indeed the one about Selune and Shar. (As opposed to, e.g., the story about Ao mentioned in the other answer.)

Answer (score 10):

According to the Forgotten Realms [wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Primordial), Ao, a god, created the multiverse.

So, Aboleths and the mortal life they enslaved would need to have existed before or outside the multiverse. Which they [were](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Aboleth) since Aboleths are natives of the [Far Realm](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Far_Realm).

Natives of the far realm are all aberrations (but not all aberrations are from the Far Realm e.g. Drider, Owlbear) so feel free to choose from the [list](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Aberrations).

Comment: Ao isn't (strictly speaking) a god.  He does have followers, but last I noticed, his "priests" didn't get spells or domains. So, if the Aboleth came into existence before the gods, but after Ao created the multiverse, that would fit the timeline.

Comment: Ao explicitly isn't a god, although the distinction probably isn't made in-universe to most people. He's an overgod, which is a different, higher class of cosmic being. He needs no worship and has complete authority over both gods and primordials (see http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Ao).

Answer (score 2):

### Likely none; in the Forgotten Realms, aboleths are only said to be older than 'most' gods, and may never have had an empire of slaves

Technically, the 5e Monster Manual entry's phrasing leaves some slight wiggle room. It doesn't necessarily say that aboleths and those early life-forms 'existed before the gods,' it only says they were there before the gods' *"coming."* That could mean before the gods' coming-into-existence, but could also be taken to mean before the gods *arrived*, from elsewhere in the multiverse, to tame the local 'mortal realm.'

As for who they ruled, in the 5e *Monster Manual* alone, one extant monster from the days of the aboleths is listed: the chuul. But, in a vague, setting-neutral way, their fluff shows they obviously weren't the only slaves, and they were uplifted, not an entirely natural race themselves.

> Survivors of the ancient aboleth empire, chuuls are crustaceans the aboleths modified and endowed with sentience. They follow the ingrained directives of their creators, as they have done since the dawn of time.
>
> ***Primeval Relics.*** In the primeval ages, aboleths ruled a vast empire that spanned the oceans of the world. In those days, the aboleths used mighty magic and bent the minds of the nascent creatures of the mortal realm. However, they were bound to the water and could not enforce their will beyond it without servants. Therefore, they created chuuls.
>
> Perfectly obedient, the chuuls collected sentient creatures and magic at the aboleths' command. Chuuls were designed to endure the ages of the world, growing in size and strength as the eons passed. When the aboleths' empire crumbled with the rise of the gods, the chuuls were cast adrift. However, these creatures continue to do what they did for the aboleths, slowly collecting humanoids, gathering treasure, amassing magic, and consolidating power.

That said, the whole idea of aboleths predating deities, or at least most deities, is a relatively recent addition to their concept, and the chuul being their uplifted slaves is even more recent (new in 5e). As late as the first 3rd edition *Monster Manual* (published October 2000), the aboleth entry didn't mention anything about ancient empires, it said:

> They know many ancient and terrible secrets, for they inherit their parents' knowledge at birth and assimilate the memories of all they consume.

And the first 4e *Monster Manual* (published June 2008) didn't mention empires either:

> ABOLETHS ARE HULKING AMPHIBIOUS CREATURES that hail
> from the Far Realm, a distant and unfathomable plane. They
> live in the Underdark, swimming through drowned crannies
> or creeping through lightless tunnels and leaving trails of
> slimy mucus in their wake. Malevolent and vile, aboleths bend
> humanoid creatures to their will, and more powerful aboleths
> can transform their minions into slimy horrors.

> #### Aboleth Lore
>
> A character knows the following information with a successful
> Dungeoneering check.
> **DC 20**: Aboleths lair in the deepest reaches of the Underdark, having slipped into the world from the Far Realm.
> However, lone aboleths can be found closer to the world’s surface, haunting ruins, deep lakes, and old temples without hope
> or want of companionship. In many of these places, kuo-toas
> serve them.
> **DC 25**: Aboleths communicate via telepathy. They can
> speak and understand Deep Speech.
> **DC 30**: Sometimes aboleths live together as a brood or
> even in a collection of broods. Aboleth overseers also populate
> their lairs with humanoids that they’ve enslaved and transformed into slimy minions.

It was 4th edition era novels that introduced the H.P. Lovecraft-esque idea that aboleths have a presence on Toril that predates almost everything else. Chapter 12 of *Plague of Spells* (published December 2008):

> "Two things. First and least, regular aboleth colonies are safely ensconced below the earth, immovable. Xxiphu is different. It is mobile. It may indeed breach to Faerûn's surface, as previous divination revealed."
>
> The monk nodded. That was certainly a worry. "And second?"
>
> "Second, Xxiphu contains the original aboleths. These are the progenitors of the race who personally squirmed into the world before it cooled from its creation fires. These aboleths were old when the sun was still young. Xxiphu is the seat of the Abolethic Sovereignty, possessed of a malignancy inconceivable, and ruled by the Eldest, an aboleth of such size its age is incalculable. Certainly it is older than when Abeir-Toril split asunder. If Xxiphu rises and the Eldest wakes, then Faerûn will face yet another catastrophe, this one directed by alien, unfeeling minds that do not perceive the world as you do, or even I."

Chapter 5 of the sequel, *City of Torment* (published September 2009):

> “The Eldest?”
>
> The woman gestured to the expanse of cold white. She pronounced in her lilting accent, “The Eldest broods over this city. It is an entity whose age surpasses most gods.”

Chapter 12:

> “I was searching dusty lore to learn more about illithids, not aboleths. Still, it caught in my memory, for its odd-ness. Written in Deep Speech, the scroll proclaimed an Abolethic Sovereignty once attempted to rule your world but was foiled. The text described a colossal thing sleeping in darkness. A nasty, terrible, many-handed, and many-eyed monster. The passage indicated its massive bulk was the result of great age. It never ceased growing, inch by inch, year by year, and century by century. Even millennium by millennium.”
>
> “The scroll was describing the Eldest?”
>
> “Just so.”
>
> “How old can it be?” Anusha asked.
>
> “It was old when Selune cried her glittering tears. Its mind buzzed with a thousand languages when mortals on Toril puzzled out their first expressive grunts. No offense. When it fell into slumber, the world yet rang with the clamor of the primordials’ forge hammers. Or so claimed the document.”

(The primordials, and the splitting of Abeir-Toril, were also entirely new additions to the origin myths of the Forgotten Realms, added in 4e.)

Chapter 19:

> “Are you worried about facing Japheth?” Seren asked the captain.
>
> “No,” said Thoster. “At least, not since your ritual.” He put his hand on the amulet cord. “Still, how often does a fellow walk into a primeval relic filled with half-petrified monsters older than gods?”

But even in these novels, it never said the aboleths predated *all* of the gods of the Forgotten Realms. Only entities in the Far Realm, the ones who have never left the Far Realm and whose release would likely end all of reality, are described as truly 'older than Lord Ao.'

It was never explored how or by whom the Abolethic Sovereignty was 'foiled' in prehistoric days, or whether they had time to establish any fallen empires on Toril or were stopped before they enslaved any lifeforms at all. If, and it's a big if, a successful aboleth empire did reign in Forgotten Realms prehistory, in another retroactive addition to canon, it's definitely only in *pre*history, unrecorded and unknown, because the most ancient recorded history is already crowded with fallen empires of its own.

*Grand History of the Realms* (published September 2007):

> #### The Days of Thunder
>
> ###### –35000 DR to –30000 DR
>
> This earliest days of recorded history begin at the end of a
> great Ice Age, some 37,000 years ago, when the last glaciations
> largely ended and the great ocean receded to reveal dry land. In
> this ancient time before The Sundering, the lands which would
> one day be identified as Faerûn, Kara-Tur, Maztica, and Zakhara
> were each but one part of a much larger super-continent named
> Merrouroboros. None of the dozen or so common races which
> populate the world today existed in this distant era. Merrouroboros knew none of the civilized folk—elves, dwarves, halflings,
> or gnomes. Nor did the savage peoples—goblins, orcs, ogres and
> their kin—inhabit the land. Though humans did exist during this
> time, they were primitive and apelike, using only simple tools
> and living in caves. These were the Days of Thunder, the time
> of the *Iqua-Tel’Quessir*, the fabled creator races.
>
> ###### c. –35000 DR
>
> Rise of the Sarrukh Empires (sauroid creator race).
>
> — The sarrukh establish the realm of Okoth, south of modern-day Mulhorand.
> Within a hundred years, most of Faerûn is theirs.
>
> ###### c. –33500 DR
>
> — Rise of the Batrachi Empires (amphibioid creator race).
>
> ###### c. –31000 DR
>
> — Rise of the Aearee Empires (avian creator race). In the west, the Aearee-Krocaa establish the grand aerie of Viakoo on Mount Havraquoar, which
> became the capital of their great nation. In the north, the Aearee-Syran
> establish their capital at the aerie of Phwiukree, in the peaks of the Star
> Mounts. In the southeast, the Aearee-Quor carve out the domain of Shara
> from their rookery in the Orsraun Mountains.

*Powers & Pantheons* (published August 1997):

> ## THE DAWN OF TIME
>
> *The following preface is excerpted from the (somewhat rambling) introduction to the multivolume* Encyclopoedia Deifica: Tales of Divinities, Both Living and Dead, Extracted Through Studious Cross-Faith Comparison and Revealed by the Hand of Oghma *by Jenelle Einhorn, Acolyte of Learned Father Hasicor Danali of the Leaves of Learning Temple and Library (1370 DR edition):*
>
> The origins of the deities of Faerûn are lost in the mists of passing time. Of the earliest days of Toril, we know only—and the fervent controversy that surrounds much of what follows must be acknowledged, for many folks have very different views of what befell in the Dawn Days—that at some point intelligent life on Toril came to be dominated by five creator races.
>
> Supreme among these were the dragons, who soon came to dominate the surface world. First to rise in dominance, but also first to fall, was a dinosauroid race that survives today only as the divergent species of lizard men, nagas, and other reptilian creatures. This race's growth was mirrored in the seas of Toril by an aquatic shapeshifting race that became amphibious and supplanted the dinosauroids. This amphibious race was the builder of proud cities on land—only to degenerate and fall back into barbarism much later under pressure from sahuagin, merfolk, and tritons. This race survives today only as the nonshapeshifting marine peoples of the locathah and the tako, and the land-dwelling, shapeshifting dopplegangers and greater dopplegangers. The fourth of the creator races was a sylvan people whose descendants are the sprites, korred, and many other small woodland folk of today. The humans were the last and most primitive of the creator races, but they have always been the most adaptable and ingenious, so their rise, when at last it came, was astonishing in both speed and planetwide efficiency.

Comment: Not sure why this gathered a downvote, thank you for all the research.

Answer (score -3):

1. Ao is a God, he's an Over God. Just like Kyrnn has the High God.
2. Ao was the one who stipulated that Gods need worshippers to survive.
3. If you read lore on Mind Flayers and Spell Weavers, you'll discover that there was once an existence without Gods. It was a failed experiment by the Spell Weavers that actually started the creation of Gods. (I think I remembered that correctly)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).